# express.Router not working in IIS hosted node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, iis, httpplatformhandler

When running my Node/Express app locally (ex. npm start), my routes load without issue. However, when the app is hosted in IIS (have tried iisnode, reverse proxy, and httpplaformhandler) it gives a 404 on the routes... specifically CANNOT GET.

These routes reside in a "routes" directory.

Here is my solution structure:

```
node_modules
public
    client.html
routes
    api1.js
    api2.js
server.js
web.config
```

Here is my server.js where the routes are loaded:

```
// MODULES AND REQUIRES
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const swaggerJsDoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
const objectMapper = require('object-mapper');
const cors = require('cors');

// Require Routes
var api1 = require('./routes/api1.js')
var api2 = require('./routes/api2.js')

// PORTS AND BASIC EXPRESS APP SETTINGS
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// CORS ALLOW ALL. NOTE IP RESTRICTIONS ARE IN PLACE
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*'
}));

// ignore request for FavIcon. so there is no error in browser
const ignoreFavicon = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.originalUrl.includes('favicon.ico')) {
      res.status(204).end();
  }
  next();
};

// Configure nonFeature
app.use(ignoreFavicon);

// Root Route - Serve Static File
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/client.html'));
});

// SWAGGER UI CONFIGURATION

// Primary Swagger Options
const options = {
  customCss: '.swagger-ui .topbar { display: none } .swagger-ui .scheme-container { display: none }'
};

// Custom Swagger Options: https://swagger.io/specification/#infoObject
const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      version: "2.0.0",
      title: "My App",
      description: "This page lists the available APIs within my app and allows you to test them.",
      contact: {
        name: "My Name"
      },
      servers: [{"url":"http://localhost:3000", "description": "Development server"}]
    }
  },
  // ['.routes/*.js'] Location for APIs
  apis: ["./routes/*.js"],
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs, options));


// ROUTES
  app.use('/api1', api1)
  app.use('/api2', api2)  

// APP LISTEN WITH SSL/HTTPS
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Here is my Web.config (currently using httpplatformhandler):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httppPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\node.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" arguments=".\server.js">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
                <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="Production" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

1. The / loads the client.html page without issue as you pull up the
   root domain
2. The /api-docs loads Swagger without issue
3. The /api1 fails with cannot get/404
4. The /api2 fails with cannot get/404

Since this is IIS, I have tried a fuller "path" to routes. Ex. routes/api1 but that fails to work.

Does Express.Router not work with an node/express app hosted in IIS?

When I set this up as an Reverse Proxy the localhost:3000 runs the /api1 without issue but the domain in IIS of mynode.com throws a Cannot Get /api1... even though it is supposed to just be a proxy.

Failed Request Tracing shows the following:

> MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
>
> ModuleName httpPlatformHandler
>
> Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
>
> HttpStatus 404
>
> HttpReason Not Found
>
> HttpSubStatus 0
>
> ErrorCode The operation completed successfully.  (0x0)

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: This is all it gave me:

MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 


ModuleName
httpPlatformHandler 

Notification
EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 

HttpStatus
404 

HttpReason
Not Found 

HttpSubStatus
0 

ErrorCode
The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0)

Comment: Finally got some time on this but I couldn't reproduce the 404 errors. `/api1` and `/api2` worked very well on my machine. So, unless you can share more details, this discussion cannot continue. BTW, some .js extensions in folder structure which I fixed, and you didn't include the contents of `api1.js` and `api2.js` which might or might not be relevant.